# dataset returning null when targeting an ID

Tags: javascript, dataset, target

here to feel stupid again. I have used this method to change the width of a div countless times. This time i am using the same dataset to just add a class to "show" a simple snackBar. However, I continue to get "null" for var x. What stupid simple thing am I missing this time? :/

I tossed in the alert(x) just to get a quick view of what I am or am not getting.

```js
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
    var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.navButton');
    //add event listener to all navButtons
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
     divs[i].addEventListener('click', showSnackBar);
    }
  });

function showSnackBar(e) {
   
 var x = document.getElementById(e.target.dataset.target);
 //alert(x)
 console.log(x)
 
 x.className = "show";
  
}
```

```html
 <div class="header">  
  
      <a class="navButton" data-target="ASnackBar">A</a>
      <a class="navButton" data-target="BSnackBar">B</a>    
 
</div>

<div id="ASnackBar" class="snackBar">Content A</div>
<div id="BSnackBar" class="snackBar">Content B</div>
```

Comment: The issue may be caused by something else. It seems to work fine as-is.